# how to deep copy a structure to each element of a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hi I am trying to do a full deep copy of a structure to each element in a vector but im not having much success

This is my structure

```
struct YUV_Buffer
{
    mfxFrameSurface1  *mSurface; //structor for video info and data
    int pSize;
    YUV_Buffer(mfxFrameSurface1 *pBuf, int  pSize) :pSize(pSize)

    {
        mSurface = new mfxFrameSurface1[pSize];
        memcpy(&mSurface, &pBuf, pSize);
    }

    YUV_Buffer(const YUV_Buffer & yuvbuf)

    {
        mSurface = new mfxFrameSurface1[yuvbuf.pSize];
        pSize = yuvbuf.pSize;
        memcpy(&mSurface, &yuvbuf.mSurface, pSize);
    }
    ~YUV_Buffer() {
        //if(mSurface != NULL)
        delete[] mSurface;
        mSurface = { 0 };

    }
};
```

and this is how im calling it

```
vector<YUV_Buffer> mBuffer;
YUV_Buffer root(pVPPSurfacesOut[nSurfIdxOut],sizeof(pVPPSurfacesOut[nSurfIdxOut]));
mBuffer.push_back(root);
```

pVPPSurfacesOut[nSurfIdxOut] is a structure called mfxFrameSurface1 which contains video frame info and video frame data I need to copy the complete structure contents to each element in the vector without over writing the previous element.

My problem with my copy structure is after the second iteration the structure crashs on the destructor ~YUV_Buffer() delete[] mSurface; in YUV_Buffer

Can anyone help out point me in the right direction 
Regards
Nigel

Comment: `memcpy(&mSurface, &yuvbuf.mSurface, pSize);` -- Why are you copying to the address of a pointer?  That should be: `memcpy(mSurface, yuvbuf.mSurface, pSize);`.  Also, what is `mfxFrameSurface1`?  If that is not a POD type, then `memcpy` is the wrong approach to begin with.

Comment: You may want to eliminate the hassles of memory management and use `std::vector<mfxFrameSurface1> mSurface;`.

Comment: Also, the issue is not with `vector`.  You could more than likely duplicate the error by just merely creating a single object and just attempt to copy, assign, and destroy the object.  Similar to this `{YUV_Buffer buf; /* fill it with data */ YUV_Buffer buf2(buf); YUV_Buffer buf3; buf3 = buf;}`

Comment: `delete[] mSurface;
    mSurface = {0};` - that second statement is pointless. You deleted `mSurface`, all access to it is now invalid regardless of its value, so why bother setting it to `0`? This in a destructor even, the `mSurface` is not going to exist in a jiffy, so its value is irrelevant.

Comment: When you say `pSize`, are you talking about the class member variable, or the argument passed to the function? The compiler can usually tell exactly which one you mean from context, but the reader may not

Comment: Second iteration? Can you show us the code that's doing the iterating?

Comment: question is , if mfxFrameSurface1 is a trivially- construable and destructible POD and shallow-copyable structure. If it isn't POD, then memcpy use is an UB. If  it contains pointers  the result is invalid semantically  and possibly leads to UB.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues.

1: memcpy should be called with pointers not the address of pointers:

```
memcpy(mSurface, pBuf, pSize);
```

2: you need to implement the rule of 3/5 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three and implement or delete the assignment operator.

A solution to both problems is to replace mfxFrameSurface1 with `std::vector` which does the memory management and copying for you:

```
struct YUV_Buffer
{
    std::vector< char >  mSurface; //structor for video info and data

    YUV_Buffer(const std::vector< char >& surface) :mSurface(surface)
    {
    }

    // YUV_Buffer(const YUV_Buffer & yuvbuf) = default; // no need to implement the copy constructor the automatic one does it all for you
    // ~YUV_Buffer() = default; // don't need a destructor either
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your input I have followed the rule_of_three solution and my crash is now gone and I change my struct as follow: